# Getting error while trying to inject RoleManager into ASP.NET Core 2.2 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to inject `RoleManager` into my controller but I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[StoreProject.Models.User]' while attempting to activate 'StoreProject.Controllers.ProductController'.

My `Startup` code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddTransient<IStoreRepository, StoreRepository>();

    services.AddIdentity<User,IdentityRole<long>>(options =>
        {
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<StoreContext>();

    services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer("Server=LAPTOP-14M18EPM\\RONSQL;Database=projectDB;Trusted_Connection=True"));
}
```

My controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<User> _roleManager;

    IStoreRepository _repository;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public AccountController(SignInManager<User> signInManager,
        UserManager<User> userManager,
        RoleManager<User> roleManager,
        IStoreRepository storeRepository,
        IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _repository = storeRepository;
        _env = env;
    }
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely this:

```
RoleManager<User> roleManager
```

should be like this:

```
RoleManager<IdentityRole<long>> roleManager
```

Basically, your issue is a type mismatch, **AddIdentity()** is registering this type **RoleManager< IdentityRole< long > >** to the dependency injection provider  and you are asking for a different type **RoleManager< User >** in your controller.